# Change css class in JavaScript - not the element assigned to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In JS, I want to change the background-image of a class without changing the element assigned to the class itself.

Is there anyway to do it? Or can changes only be made for specific elements,
and I'll have to define a class for each background-image?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create/edit a style tag with JavaScript if that's what you want.

Comment: I dont want to use ID, because I have many switches between elements that have the same purpose. I'm building a maze and trying to change the figure's image for every arrow movement - therefore it is very straightforward to assign a class for all the path cells and a suitable class for the player.

Comment: The cascade in CSS let you change the element's background by changing its outer-elements. In example: `<p class="image1"><span></span></p>` change the class of p can change the background of span without changing the span!

Comment: but it won't work for future elements

Comment: This objective description is not very clear. Please put a bit more effort into explaining your issue properly so it is understandable to all and includes all scenarios. See [ask]

Answer (score 3):

You can try jQuery :

```
$('.class-name').css('background-image','img-url');
```

If you wanna change multiple properties, use it like this :

```
$('.class-name').css({'prop1':'val1','prop2':'val2',.....,'propn':'valn'});
```

You can also this with id's and tags names

Comment: with the caveat that this will affect all the elements that are using said class

Comment: thanks, but I want the effect to remain for the future elements I'll assign with class. so that's no use...

Comment: I think it's pretty much obvious, since classes are appointed to many elements, styles of classes are applied to all those elements

Comment: @MrGeek not future ones ... that should also be obvious

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by future use.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class of your element like this:

```
document.getElementById("idOfElement").className = "newClass";
```

Just clone the normal class to newClass or whatever you are going to name the new class, but change the background-image property. That way when you change the class, the only thing changing is the background.